# belongsToMany with multiple forieng key in Laravel

Tags: laravel

By default, laravel support two foreing_key in a pivot table. And both attach and detach methods work properly. But in case we have triple foreign key in a pivot table, what is the proper way to retrieve and insert data to the pivot table.

**Tables**

```
Orders:
id       bill_number

Products
id       name

Colors
id       name

order_details:
id       order_id       product_id        color_id        price
```

**My Models:**

```
class Order extends Model
{

    public function client() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
    }
    public function items() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'order_items');
    }
}

class Product extends Model
{
    //
    public function orders() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order', 'order_items');
    }
}

class Color extends Model
{
    //
    public function orders() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order', 'order_items');
    }
}
```

Now I want to get or insert order_items with the following attribute:

```
order_id       product_id       color_id       price
1              1                1              800
```

**Products:**

1. Shirt
2. Pant
3. Jacket

**Color:**

1. Gray
2. White
3. Black

Now I want to list all items of order with product name, color and price;
If I want to insert an order of shirt with black color and price of 800, how should I figure it out? And Also If I list all order items with color and prices which method should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it with sql join as bellow:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function items() {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'order_details')->withPivot('id', 'price')
                        ->join('colors', 'order_details.color_id', '=', 'colors.id')
                        ->select('products.*', 'colors.name as color_name');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [intermediate table model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models). Then you can define your relationship with color on that model.

Comment: Thank you @jason-houle. That is a good option but I don't know how to query items with product name and color name?

Comment: I did not test this but I think something like the following would work:
`$order->with([
 'product' => function($query) {
  $query->where('id', $productID);
 },
 'color' => function($query) {
  $query->where('id', $colorID);
 }
])->get();`

Answer (score 1):

A little bit "hacky" but you can use `withPivot` and `wherePivot`.

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function orders() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order', 'order_items')->withPivot('color_id', 'price');
    }
}
```

Then you may insert a new record like this:

```
$product->orders()->attach($orderId, ['color_id' => 1, 'price' => 800]);
```

And query it with:

```
$products = Product::whereHas('orders', function ($query) {
    $query->where('color_id', '=', 1);
})->get();
```

Comment: Thank you. I did what you said. But when I list my order items, I can get product name but I can't get color name too. Can you help me please?

Comment: @AliBabaAzimi When you're iterating through your orders  `foreach ($product-> orders as $order)` you'll have access to a `pivot` attribute. So you might get like this: `$order->pivot-> color_id;`

Comment: Yes I can but I don't need the id, I need color name

Answer (score 0):

I would use a double pivot table using a **same** order_id for order_product and order_color. Another solution is using a Polymorphic Relationship https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

Comment: Thank you @LuisJorquera can you help me with querying from two pivot table? or if you can help me how to design this with polymorphic relationship?